# Request method 'HEAD' not supported on Windows 10

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

I have a problem with a web application that I'm developping. My application is very simple, is the typical application MVC with Spring Framework (4.1.5), Tomcat 7 and Java 7, nothing special. I'm developping my application in a laptop with windows 10, Eclipse Kepler, XAMPP and all my controllers and methods that can access by url have a request method with GET. When I access to any url of my application, sometimes in the console appears the follow warning:

```
WARN [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] - Request method 'HEAD' not supported
```

Somebody says that I need configure my controllers adding the request method HEAD, but I don't understand one think. I have set the same web application, with the same version of Spring, the same version of Tomcat, the same version of  Java, etc... everything the same on other laptop but with windows 7, is the unique difference and with this laptop don't appears the warning. I'm turning on crazy, I don't understand nothing. Somebody have any explanation

Comment: Some browsers will send HEAD requests; others will not.

Comment: I tried the same version of chrome on both laptops and on one appears the warning and the other not.

Comment: Check what the request is coming from in Fiddler.  Also check browser extensions.

Comment: I do not know how to thank you, I think I've found the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of SLaks I tried Fiddler. With this application I saw that sometimes there was a process that makes a request to my application. This process is a pluggin RealPlayer to download videos. In the laptop with windows 7 not active and therefore had not appeared the warning